# Python list index out of range python on an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, while-loop

I'm trying to go through an array from any position l to the end, but once it reaches the last position instead of leaving the while cycle it shows me an error "list index out of range"

```
while l <= len(ordenado):
      ñ = ordenado[l]
      contador2 = contador2+ñ
      l = l+1
```

I've seen many answers about this theme but I haven't been able to apply it to my problem, also any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to use `l < len(ordenado)` instead of `<=`

Comment: @bla He might not know it yet, but what he really wants is a `for` loop. Or just `sum()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python list are 0 indexed so you need to use.

```
while l < len(ordenado):
```

for your case for loop is more suitable.

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i, item in enumerate(mylist):
    print(i, item) #where i will be 0,1,2 and item will be a,b,c
```

Comment: Is there a language which arrays/lists are not 0-indexed?

Comment: I think vba is.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
while l <= len(ordenado):
```

With:

```
while l < len(ordenado):
```

The reason is that python list indices range from zero to 
`len(ordenado) - 1`.

#### Example

```
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> mylist[0]
'a'
>>> mylist[len(mylist)-1]
'c'
>>> mylist[len(mylist)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As you can see, `mylist[len(mylist)-1]` accesses the last element of the list.  Any index larger than that will generate an `IndexError`.